# Does The (US) 'First Time Home Buyer's Credit' Still Exist?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, first-time-home-buyer, illinois

I was told by a realtor, in the state of Illinois, today that there is currently a program that will provide '$7,500 in assistance for someone who has not owned a house in the past 3 years'.  I tried to find an official source to get more information about the program, but I'm having trouble finding it.

I can find a federal tax credit of $7,500 for first time home-buyers described on the IRS's website (https://www.irs.gov/uac/First-Time-Homebuyer-Credit-1) but it seems to only apply to houses purchased in 2008-2010.

Can someone please clarify?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep - you're absolutely right.  Thank you.

Comment: Ask the realtor to provide a citation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that there is some kind of a state-sponsored program in IL, not sure about the details. It is not a tax credit, though. Read about it at the [IHDA website](http://www.ihda.org/homeowner/gettingLoan.htm).

> First-time homebuyers in **Boone, Cook, DeKalb, Fulton, Kane, Marion,
>   McHenry, St. Clair, Will** or **Winnebago** counties can get $7,500 in down
>   payment assistance with a competitive interest rate for a secure,
>   30-year fixed rate mortgage. 1STHomeIllinois is tailored for
>   first-time homebuyers, Veterans, or anyone who hasn't owned a home in
>   the last three years living in one of the above 10 counties.

The Federal tax credit was indeed only for 2008-2010.